# JQuery's promise() and ClojureScript

Tags: jquery, clojure, clojurescript

How might I best implement the following jQuery function in ClojureScript?

```
$(element).promise().done(function() {
    // Magic
});
```

All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(-> ".class" js/$ (.promise) (.done #(prn "Magic")))`